# Numpy Find Index of Maximum Value inside small range of array

Tags: python, numpy, search, max, intervals

I have a two dimensional array of the form

```
 data = array([
       [  0.23        ,   0.61070541],
       [  1.12        ,   0.94622007],
       [  2.33        ,   0.20868555],
       [  3.23        ,   0.26452314],
       [  4.67        ,   0.93988767],
       [  5.17        ,   0.05736691],
       [  6.74        ,   0.54063927],
       [  7.58        ,   0.3045981 ],
       [  8.48        ,   0.13873822],
       [  9.47        ,   0.27759926],
       [ 10.12        ,   0.27030156]])
```

and i want to find the maximum in the second column limited to a interval given by the first column. I want to look in the rows 5 to 8 and find the maximum row index for the maximum in the second column. In the given data set that would be row 6, data[6] = 6. , 0.54063927. My goal is to get index 6 using numpy. So far i would have done

```
data_interval = data[ np.where( (data[:,0] > 5) & data[:,0] < 9 ) ]
max_interval = data_interval.max(axis = 0)[1]
index = np.where(data == [None, max_interval])[0]
```

This works if the maximum value does not appear another time in the data outside the interval. Otherwise i would get in the last np.where call multiple indices. Overall this feels unwieldy and i was wondering if there was a faster way that yields only the index in the interval. **I want the absolut index in respect to the total data array**, not the index of the data_interval array.
Generally i find it difficult to do sorting/searching data in numpy for data sets that comes pairwise like (x,y) based only on x or y once the data is together in an array. Hints/Advice for handling such problems are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by first *masking out* the values where the condition does *not* hold, and then use `argmax`, to calculate the index where the second column is the maximum.

So we mask with:

```
data_masked = np.ma.masked_where((data[:,0] < 5) | (data[:,0] > 9), data[:,1])
```

So here the condition is the *opposite* of the filter condition: all rows for which `data[:0] < 5` or `data[:0] > 9` are masked out. Note that we already make a projection to the second column. The intermediate result is then:

```
>>> np.ma.masked_where((data[:,0] < 5) | (data[:,0] > 9), data[:,1])
masked_array(data=[--, --, --, --, --, 0.05736691, 0.54063927, 0.3045981,
                   0.13873822, --, --],
             mask=[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
                   False,  True,  True],
       fill_value=1e+20)
```

and then we calculate the index with:

```
index = np.argmax(b)
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it myself before with masking but did not know how to apply the mask properly to hte second column. Do the other mask functions work similar and mask the data that is passed along as secondary argument ?

Comment: @HansWurst: well the idea is that for the masked elements the value is not available, so that means that  - conceptually - they do not have access to the elements afaik.